# different liquid in a container produce different sound

Tags: acoustics

Does the type of liquid in a container affect the sound it produces?

example like milk, water and coffee produce a minute different sound

Answer (score 1):

The denser the liquid, the easier the sound will be able to travel through it, making it louder than if the liquid were less dense. Whole cow milk has a density of about 1.03, water 1.00, and coffee is most likely in-between water and milk. This means that if a sound of the same amplitude (loudness) is played through each, you will hear them with in this decreasing order of amplitude: milk, coffee, and then water, which is the quietest.